# Directories owned by a number instead of usernames

Tags: file, unix, permissions

I am trying to write to a directory on a network folder but am facing file permission issues. Upon investigation I found that the directories I create are owned by two types of users. When viewing permissions using ls -l. A few directories have my username as the owner while others have a 'weird number'. I can write to the files owned by the 'weird number' but not my username.

My userId is different from this number
This number is not a userID for any other user on the system.
Any idea about what that number is

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you see userid's numerically it means that the system your shell runs on does not know the username for this userid.

One typical case of this is if you extracted a tar archive from a different system without the -o flag. In this case the numbers would be the userid from the originating system where the tar archive was created and they may not exist in your system.

Another way can also be that you mount a network folder, but your system does not know the usernames for those userid's - in which case it will display the userid numbers.

This problem can also extend to groups (files having a groupid which does not correspond to an existing group on this system) in an analogue way.

Comment: Hi Tobias, thank you for the useful reply. I am trying to write to this directory on the network folder. The number (not sure if its the userId) is not my userId because I tried checking my userId and its different from what the network folder shows its owner as. Another question is that how to set permissions to this network folder? who owns it?

Comment: Hi Ruby, It is owned by another user <userid> which does not exist on your system. Likely the same is true for the group. So you need to change it on a system which knows this user, that should be possible on the system which is exporting the network folder. Can you remote login to that other system and check there?

Comment: I was trying to edit my question to the following:     The network folder is owned by my username to which I thought I have permission to write, but when I issue commands I am identified as a constant number (not my userId) so how do I modify this permission to identify this number as my sername?